# Simulating nondeterministic space-bounded computation using randomness

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, randomness, space-bounded, nondeterminism

Let's suppose that a language $L \in$ NSPACE($f(n)$) where $f(n)$ is $O(\log n)$. And now let's suppose that I have a probabilistic Turing machine. Can this machine run in $O(f(n))$ space and answer yes when $x \in L$ with $\Pr(yes) > 1/2$ and answer no when $x \not\in L$ with $\Pr(no) = 1$? Let's suppose I dont care about time as long as the machine halts.

Comment: 1) Please use LaTeX. 2) I assume you want $f(n) \in \omega(f(n))$ because the answer is trivial for $f \in \Theta(f(n))$.

Comment: relevant question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4448/1037

Comment: I am speaking about probabilistic not quantum turing machines. Can you further enlighten me with this question?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking if RL contains NL ?

Comment: I think you are right, as I am not so familiar i didn't understand it in the first place

Answer (score 5):

My comment was incorrect, and in fact the answer to your question is YES. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL_%28complexity%29):

> Suppose C is the complexity class of
>   problems solvable in logarithmithic
>   space with probabilistic Turing
>   machines that never accept incorrectly
>   but are allowed to reject incorrectly
>   less than 1/3 of the time; this is
>   called one-sided error. The constant
>   1/3 is arbitrary; any x with 0 ≤ x <
>   1/2 would suffice.
>
> It turns out that C = NL. Notice that
>   C, unlike its deterministic
>   counterpart L, is not limited to
>   polynomial time, because although it
>   has a polynomial number of
>   configurations it can use randomness
>   to escape an infinite loop. If we do
>   limit it to polynomial time, we get
>   the class RL, which is contained in
>   but not known or believed to equal NL.

Comment: Note that the question specifies that the machine “halts.”  If we interpret this as “halts always,” then I think the class is RL, not NL.  If we interpret it as “halts [with probability 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely),” yes, it is NL.

Comment: What is the difference between “halts always” and “halts with probability 1?” After being confused about this for a long time, mainly because Oded Goldreich redefines RSPACE to incorporate a time bound in his lecture notes, I have been finally convinced by the survey of Saks and a paper by Watrous that RSPACE(s)=NSPACE(s) for any space bound s; so in particular, for s= log n. RL, originally a shorthand for RSPACE(log n), nowadays denotes the more interesting class of languages that are recognized with positive one-sided error by logspace PTMs with polynomial time bounds.