# Which results make quantum space interesting?

Tags: quantum-computing, space-bounded

Time-bounded quantum computation is obviously very interesting. What about space-bounded quantum computation?

I know many interesting results for quantum computation with sublogarithmic space bounds and various kind of quantum automata models.

On the other hand, it was shown that unbounded-error probabilistic and quantum space are equivalent for any space constructable $ s(n) \in \Omega(\log(n)) $ (Watrous, [1999](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000099916550) and [2003](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00037-003-0177-8)).

I wonder whether there are some specific results making quantum space interesting (by **excluding** sublogarithmic-space and automata models).

(I am aware of this entry: [Quantum analogues of SPACE complexity classes](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4448/7358).)

Comment: Sorry for ignorance. What is relation between space-bounded quantum computation and quantum circuit model?

Comment: @Alex'qubeat': It is convenient to use Turing machines for space-bounded computation. Circuit model is appropriate for time-bounded computation.

Comment: Why it is more convenient? Is it convenient in quantum or classical case? From naive point of view it is unbounded space more convenient for (classical) Turing machines.

Comment: @Alex'qubeat': It is convenient for both classical and quantum cases. I can highly recommend you the fundamental paper on this subject by Stearns, Hartmanis, and Lewis: "Hierarchies of memory limited computations" (http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/FOCS.1965.11). You can also check both papers of Watrous (mentioned above) and a recent paper by Melkebeek and Watson (http://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v008a001/).

Comment: Thank you, I have seen that, but there is also work using quantum circuits http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1467 that, at least does not suffer from necessity to manage with few different definitions of QTM.

Answer (score 5):

I think Amnon Ta-Shma's new result is a good answer to my own question.

- [Amnon Ta-Shma: Inverting well conditioned matrices in quantum logspace. STOC 2013: 881-890](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2488608.2488720). ([copy from author's website](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amnon/Papers/T.stoc13.IntQLog.pdf))

> ...  We show that the inverse of a well conditioned matrix can be approximated in quantum logspace with intermediate measurements. This should be compared with the best known classical algorithm for the problem that requires $\Omega(\log^2 n)$ space. We also show how to approximate the spectrum of a normal matrix, or the singular values of an arbitrary matrix, with $\epsilon$ additive accuracy, and how to approximate the singular value decomposition (SVD) of a matrix whose singular values are well separated. ...